# C# code error (calculating)

Tags: c#

Below I have a small C# program that reads from my file (hours.txt) but I am having issues fixing the //calculate area. I have tried several things to fix it with no outcomes, so does anyone here have any idea how to fix this?

```
        //Declare ints
        string [] hoursArray = new string[30];
        string high = hoursArray[0];
        string low = hoursArray[1];
        string average = hoursArray[0];
        int total = 0;
        double avarage = 0;

        //Input
        StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader("hours.txt");
        int coutner = 0;
        string line;
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        while (line != null) //check while not EOF
        {
            hoursArray[total] = line;
            total++;
            line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        }
        fileSR.Close();

        for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(hoursArray[index]);
        }

        //Calculate
        for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
        {
            total = total + hoursArray[index];
            if (hoursArray[index] < low)
            {
                low = hoursArray[index];
            }
            if (hoursArray[index] > high)
            {
                high = hoursArray[index];
            }
        }
        avarage = (double)total / hoursArray.Length;

        //Output
        Console.WriteLine("Total hours parked: " + total);
        Console.WriteLine("Avarage hours parked: " + avarage.ToString("N2"));
        Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = " + low);
        Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = " + high);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: is this OK `string average = hoursArray[0];`? Shouldn't it be `string average = hoursArray[2];`

Comment: you can improve the code by changing that `while` loop to `do..while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing based off your code, but it looks like it's because your hoursArray, high, low, and average values are all strings - these should be numeric.

Modify your variable declarations to:

```
    List<double> hoursArray = new List<double>; // changing this to a list 
    double high = double.MinValue; // initialize at the min for initial comparison
    double low = double.MaxValue; // initialize at the max 
    double total = 0;
    double avarage = 0;
```

When you're reading from the file, convert the string values you read to doubles:

```
    //Input
    StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader("hours.txt");
    string line = fileSR.ReadLine();
    while (line != null) //check while not EOF
    {
        double hours = 0;
        if (double.TryParse(line, out hours)) // check if line is a valid double
        {
           hoursArray.Add(hours);
        }
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();
    }
    fileSR.Close();
```

Now you'll be using numbers in your Calculate section instead of strings:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Count; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(hoursArray[index]);
    }

    //Calculate
    for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Count; index++)
    {
        total = total + hoursArray[index];
        if (hoursArray[index] < low)
        {
            low = hoursArray[index];
        }
        if (hoursArray[index] > high)
        {
            high = hoursArray[index];
        }
    }
    avarage = (double)total / hoursArray.Count;

    //Output
    Console.WriteLine("Total hours parked: " + total);
    Console.WriteLine("Avarage hours parked: " + avarage.ToString("N2"));
    Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = " + low);
    Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = " + high);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

**Note:** I have not tested this code.